# Is there a crypto library for AES using ECB cypher and PCKS5 padding on WP7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, encryption, aes

I need the ability to decrypt data supplied from a client using the AES encryption with ECB cypher and PCKS5 padding on the device.

The AesManaged class does not support changing the padding or the cypher and RijndaelManaged  is not supported in WP7.

Are there any crypto libraries out there built for WP7 supporting these configurations?

Comment: Can't you simply unpad the data manually? PCKS5 is not that complicated. (Also, ECB mode is not secure, you should think about changing the client, too.)

Comment: the 'client' i have no control over...

Comment: Yes, just send a note to its developer.

Comment: you do realise developers don't run companies don't you...

Comment: Yes, sorry if this sounds wrong. If you must implement ECB, do it (it is still better than no encryption at all). I just said that you should notify whoever responsible for the decision that this should be ECB, that this might not be the right way to do it.

Comment: the 'new' guy the other end already did this, this was originally developed for iPhone and so the content structure & encryption is kind of fixed for now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BouncyCastle do a C# crypto library, http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/.  I don't know how well it works on Win7.

As  Paŭlo pointed out, ECB is not secure.  If you can, change to CBC or CTR mode.

You may well find that 'AES' and 'Rijndael' are compatible.  AES is a subset of Rijndael so they can usually be made to work together, especially if the source is AES.

Comment: I've had all these thoughts and I've not be able to port Bouncy Castle successfully to WP7, just wondering if anyone else had...

Comment: PKCS5/PKCS7 padding is very easy to remove programatically, it is one of `0x01`, `0x0202`, `0x030303`, etc  AES is Rijndael with a 128 bit block size and (usually) a 128 or 256 bit key.

Comment: I written up getting Bouny Castle working on WP7 - http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html

Answer (score 2):

check [SecureBlackBox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/editions.php) out... not affiliated, only a happy customer...